# Using Eclipse with HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: eclipse, html, ide, html5boilerplate

I just got my new computer and I'm going to learn an IDE fresh.  Everyone suggests Eclipse; therefore, I'll go with that.  I downloaded Java EE for I may use it later for java programming also.  I don't mind the bloat.

What I want to achieve is that every time I create a new website project that [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) also gets created as a template to the project.  Anyone know how to achieve this?

Also any additional plugins for web dev or anything to do helpful with web development ideas with eclipse would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java EE eventually, I think the best strategy would be creating a Maven archetype.  This way once you have your baseline project definition, you can archetype it and create all your subsequent projects from that.

[Apache - Guide to creating archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)

If you don't have Maven yet, you can [get it here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html).

And the Maven Eclipse plugin can be installed from the update site:  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Finally, since you are new to Eclipse, you can install plugins from Help > Install New Software.  Best of luck!  I know that's probably a lot to take in.